# Azure Service Fabric missing DLL on production server: FabricCommon.dll

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I have created an actor service, which runs on a development cluster. An ASP.NET application (hosted separately via IIS), connects to the cluster and uses the actors. This works fine.

But when I deploy everything to the production environment, the ASP.NET application fails to connect to the cluster with the below exception. The cluster is hosted on-premise (Windows 2012 R2).

```
The type initializer for 'Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services.ServiceTrace' threw an exception.

Stacktrace:
   at Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services.Common.FabricServiceConfig.TryGetConfigPackageObject(String configPackageName, ConfigurationPackage& package)
   at Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services.Common.FabricServiceConfig.GetSettingsFilePath(String configPackageName)
   at Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services.Common.FabricServiceConfig.GetConfig()
   at Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services.Common.FabricServiceConfigSection.Initialize()
   at Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services.Communication.FabricTransport.Common.FabricTransportSettings.LoadFrom(String sectionName, String filepath, String configPackageName)
   at Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services.Communication.FabricTransport.Common.FabricTransportSettings.TryLoadFrom(String sectionName, FabricTransportSettings& settings, String filepath, String configPackageName)
   at Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services.Communication.FabricTransport.Common.FabricTransportSettings.GetDefault(String sectionName)
   at Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Actors.Remoting.FabricTransport.FabricTransportActorRemotingProviderAttribute.CreateServiceRemotingClientFactory(IServiceRemotingCallbackClient callbackClient)
   at Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Actors.Client.ActorProxyFactory.CreateServiceRemotingClientFactory(Type actorInterfaceType)
   at Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Actors.Client.ActorProxyFactory.GetOrCreateServiceRemotingClientFactory(Type actorInterfaceType)
   at Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Actors.Client.ActorProxyFactory.CreateActorProxy[TActorInterface](Uri serviceUri, ActorId actorId, String listenerName)
   at Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Actors.Client.ActorProxy.Create[TActorInterface](ActorId actorId, Uri serviceUri, String listenerName)

Inner Exception:
innerExceptionType: System.DllNotFoundException
innerStacktrace:
   at System.Fabric.Interop.NativeCommon.FabricGetConfigStore(Guid& riid, IFabricConfigStoreUpdateHandler updateHandler)
   at System.Fabric.Common.NativeConfigStore.CreateHelper(IFabricConfigStoreUpdateHandler updateHandler)
   at System.Fabric.Interop.Utility.WrapNativeSyncInvoke[TResult](Func`1 func, String functionTag, String functionArgs)
   at System.Fabric.Interop.Utility.RunInMTA[TResult](Func`1 func)
   at Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Common.Tracing.Trace.InitializeFromConfigStore()
   at Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services.ServiceTrace..cctor()
innerExceptionMessage: Unable to load DLL 'FabricCommon.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)
exceptionType: System.TypeInitializationException
```

It seems that the **FabricCommon.dll** could not be found on the web server (which hosts the ASP.NET).

I found that this file is part of the cluster installation package. On the development machine and cluster machines, the file is located here: `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Service Fabric\bin\Fabric\Fabric.Code\FabricCommon.dll`. But it is apparently not a dependency installed via NuGet in the client application.

Do I missed to install any prerequisites on the web server? Do I have to include the DLL manually?

Comment: The described error occurs, when I try to create an ActorProxy. But in the meantime (thanks to this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38015934/how-to-create-actor-proxy-to-remote-service-fabric-cluster) I have learned, that using an ActorProxy from a client application outside of the cluster does not work well currently. Using a stateless WebAPI service within the same SF application is an alternative (as shown here: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/service-fabric-dotnet-web-reference-app).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you need to install Service Fabric SDK on the web server.

See the link below:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-fabric-get-started/

Comment: Hi. This solved my particular problem (missing DLL). However I had to convert the web server into a dev machine. And connecting to the remote cluster is still an issue. In the meantime I found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38015934/how-to-create-actor-proxy-to-remote-service-fabric-cluster).

Answer (score 11):

Add the following Service Fabric bin path to your PATH environment variable:

```
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Service Fabric\bin\Fabric\Fabric.Code
```

Also set execution policy to unrestricted:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Force -Scope CurrentUser
```

Answer (score 1):

I have this happen at one point in my dev machine. All I did was to reinstall the Service Fabric SDK.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. Reboot my machine solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

For cases when you can't install Service Fabric SDK on target environment there is an option to use [Service Fabric REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/servicefabric/).

Here is [my repo](https://github.com/lAnubisl/ServiceFabricHttpApiClient) with API client written in C# which can resolve service using this API