# How to create actor proxy to remote Service Fabric cluster

Tags: c#, azure-service-fabric

According to the Service Fabric docs (https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-fabric-reliable-actors-introduction/), an actor proxy is created this way:

```
ActorId actorId = ActorId.NewId();

IMyActor myActor = ActorProxy.Create<IMyActor>(actorId, new Uri("fabric:/MyApp/MyActorService"));

await myActor.DoWorkAsync();
```

Ok, this works and connects to my local cluster. But I cannot figure out how to create a proxy to a *remote* cluster? (I have a three-node cluster with the IPs 10.0.10.10, 10.0.11.10, 10.0.12.10.)

I also tried to use the **ServicePartitionResolver**, which is explained here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-fabric-reliable-services-communication/, but without success.

Comment: Good question. I for one would like to see this too. Being able to interact with Actors this way would open up a lot of application possibilities (i.e. non web-based clients, but where cluster is used as back-end for one or the other reason). Also possibly make debugging faster/easier (i.e. actor (and it's service) in question is temporarily executing locally).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ActorProxy and ServiceProxy today works best for connecting to actors and services within the cluster. You can expose a stateless service with -1 instance count that can accept the user requests and then use Actor and Service remoting to connect to the actor service within the cluster. In the future release we may offer out of the box application gateway that supports remoting.

Comment: Thanks for clarification. In my case I use an ASP.NET application hosted via IIS on separate servers to handle web requests. The web tier forwards to SF as required. I guess that a better approach is to use a stateless WebAPI service within the same SF application to handle the request directly within the same cluster (as shown here: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/service-fabric-dotnet-web-reference-app).

Comment: Yes, you need that stateless Web API service to serve as an ingress point for users, and then inside there you can use ActorProxy and ServiceProxy.