# Using Azure service fabric actors from a UWP client

Tags: uwp, azure-service-fabric, service-fabric-actor, client-applications

I am interested in using Azure Service Fabric Reliable Actors, they seem like a great server-side solution for a multi-user application I am trying to develop. Unfortunately, I can find no information about how a UWP client application can utilze service fabric actors. Client applications are supposed to use the ActorProxy to call methods in remote actor objects (implementing IActor interfaces). Unfortunately, the Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Actors NuGet package seems to only support .NET 4.5 -- not the UWP platform. Am I overlooking something? Is there any high-level way to access service fabric actors from a UWP client? If so, any information or links on the topic would be greatly appreciated! Alan

Comment: I suppose for these kind of scenario's it would be best to put a stateless web api service in front of the actors the UWP client can talk to.

Comment: Yep, what Peter says: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38018995/5946937