# Define endpoint for Reliable Actor in Service Fabric(on premise setup)

Tags: azure-service-fabric, service-fabric-stateful, service-fabric-actor, service-fabric-stateless

I am setting up a Service fabric cluster on premise and Have a Reliable Actor defined. I have published the application to the cluster.

I am facing difficulty in exposing an Endpoint so that the client can consume.
I tried adding endpoint in ServiceManifest and locally deploying the cluster. But the cluster fails to deploy, the moment an Endpoint is added.

NOTE: I am using Actor Service template of Service fabric and added Reliable Actor.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should probably create a stateless web api that connects your client to your actors. Source: [How to create actor proxy to remote Service Fabric cluster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38015934/how-to-create-actor-proxy-to-remote-service-fabric-cluster/38018995#38018995)

Comment: I have created a web api that connects to actor through a stateless service.
But I am unable to browse the api on the exposed endpoint.
I am using the sample https://github.com/Azure-Samples/service-fabric-dotnet-web-reference-app 
Am i missing anything?

Comment: have you got any GET endpoints? i suggest trying POSTMAN to test that endpoint. Other things worth considering are firewall rules which might be preventing you to connect to your api if its in a different machine.. or i am not sure if the local cluster manager allows remote connections as it is for development only